# MongoDB $sort aggregation

Tags: javascript, python, mongodb, sorting

I have data base with user's activities and I'd like to count active users and number of activities that they made for each month, then sort result first by year, and each year sort by month!

I've got query:

```
query = {
        "activities": {
            "$exists": 1
        },
        "activities.started": {
            "$exists": 1,
            "$type": MONGODB_DATE_TYPE,
            "$gte": datetime(2011, 6, 1),
            "$lte": datetime(2013, 10, 1)
        }
    }
```

Then, I made pipeline like this:

```
pipeline = [
        {'$project': {
            '_id': 1,
            'activities': 1
        }},
        {'$unwind': "$activities"},
        {'$match': query},
        {'$group': {
            '_id': {"y": {"$year": "$activities.started"},
                    "m": {"$month": "$activities.started"}},
            'users': {'$addToSet': "$_id"},
            'activities_count': {"$sum": 1},
        }},
        {"$sort": {
            "_id.y": 1,
            "_id.m": 1,
        }}
    ]

    results = col.aggregate(pipeline)
    results = results.get("result", [])
```

But, this **$sort** operation doesn't work good, It did not sort by **_id.y** and **_id.m**, only by **_id.m**!

I've been following this [link for mongodb $sort](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/sort/) and there is a example that shows that's possible to sort by two values there .

So, my question is : How can I order result first by year, then each year by month?

## EDIT

For example when I put `pdb` below `result` variable and type function:

```
for res in results : print res["_id"]
```

I got this results :

```
{u'y': 2012, u'm': 1}
{u'y': 2013, u'm': 1}
{u'y': 2012, u'm': 2}
{u'y': 2013, u'm': 2}
{u'y': 2012, u'm': 3}
{u'y': 2013, u'm': 3}
{u'y': 2012, u'm': 4}
{u'y': 2013, u'm': 4}
{u'y': 2012, u'm': 5}
{u'y': 2013, u'm': 5}
{u'y': 2011, u'm': 6}
{u'y': 2012, u'm': 6}
{u'y': 2013, u'm': 6}
{u'y': 2011, u'm': 7}
{u'y': 2012, u'm': 7}
{u'y': 2013, u'm': 7}
{u'y': 2011, u'm': 8}
{u'y': 2012, u'm': 8}
{u'y': 2013, u'm': 8}
{u'y': 2011, u'm': 9}
{u'y': 2012, u'm': 9}
{u'y': 2013, u'm': 9}
{u'y': 2011, u'm': 10}
{u'y': 2012, u'm': 10}
{u'y': 2011, u'm': 11}
{u'y': 2012, u'm': 11}
{u'y': 2011, u'm': 12}
{u'y': 2012, u'm': 12}
```

Comment: You've got some stray trailing commas, but other than that it looks right.  Can you update your question to provide a couple of sample docs that reproduce the problem?

Comment: I updated, can u figure problem out ? It just sort by month!

Comment: I'm pretty sure the problem is that you're using Python which doesn't maintain the order of the fields in dicts.  Try using a `$sort` value like this instead: `[("_id.y", 1), ("_id.m", 1)]`

Comment: I got this error : _TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'_ .. But this output as u can see as result is executed inside of mongodb.. I made aggregate by myself into mongodb instead of using python!

Comment: It would be helpful if you loaded a sample document from your collection, per @JohnnyHK

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand you! How can I do it ?

Answer (score 1):

Like @JohnnyHK mentioned in the comments python dictionaries (unlike js objects) are unordered. If you want to use sorting on curosr you would use something like this `db.foo.find().sort([("foo", 1), ("bar": 1)]))` but this syntax is not supported in aggregation `$sort`. You can use [`bson.son.SON`](http://api.mongodb.org/python/current/api/bson/son.html#module-bson.son) object or [`collections.OrderedDict`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict) instead:

```
from bson.son import SON

pipeline = [
        {'$project': {
            '_id': 1,
            'activities': 1
        }},
        {'$unwind': "$activities"},
        {'$match': query},
        {'$group': {
            '_id': {"y": {"$year": "$activities.started"},
                    "m": {"$month": "$activities.started"}},
            'users': {'$addToSet': "$_id"},
            'activities_count': {"$sum": 1},
        }},
        {"$sort": SON([
            ("_id.y", 1),
            ("_id.m", 1)
        ])}
    ]
```

**EDIT**

Actually I think that in your case this should be enough:

```
pipeline = [
       {'$project': {
           '_id': 1,
           'activities': 1
       }},
       {'$unwind': "$activities"},
       {'$match': query},
       {'$group': {
           '_id': {"y": {"$year": "$activities.started"},
                   "m": {"$month": "$activities.started"}},
           'users': {'$addToSet': "$_id"},
           'activities_count': {"$sum": 1},
       }},
       {"$sort": {"_id": 1}}
   ]
```

If sort filed is document MonogoDB seems to perform sorting field by field. Order of the fields in a document can change during updates and in the general case it wouldn't work. Here however order of fields is defined in the `$group` phase and document are not modified after that so it shouldn't be a problem.

Sorting by embedded document - shell example:

```
> db.bar.insert({foobar: {foo: 2012, bar: 1}})
> db.bar.insert({foobar: {foo: 2012, bar: 5}})
> db.bar.insert({foobar: {foo: 2012, bar: 3}})
> db.bar.insert({foobar: {foo: 2010, bar: 5}})
> db.bar.insert({foobar: {foo: 2010, bar: 1}})
> db.bar.insert({foobar: {foo: 2013, bar: 5}})
> db.bar.insert({foobar: {foo: 2013, bar: 3}})
> db.bar.find({}, {_id: 0}).sort({foobar: 1})
{ "foobar" : { "foo" : 2010, "bar" : 1 } }
{ "foobar" : { "foo" : 2010, "bar" : 5 } }
{ "foobar" : { "foo" : 2012, "bar" : 1 } }
{ "foobar" : { "foo" : 2012, "bar" : 3 } }
{ "foobar" : { "foo" : 2012, "bar" : 5 } }
{ "foobar" : { "foo" : 2013, "bar" : 3 } }
{ "foobar" : { "foo" : 2013, "bar" : 5 } }
```

Comment: I've already tried to solve it by SON, but without success ! It got same result !

Comment: Could you post some example documents? For example output from `from bson.json_util import dumps; dumps(col.find(query).limit(5))`